# Return RDD of largest N values from another RDD in SPARK

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm trying to filter an RDD of tuples to return the largest N tuples based on key values. I need the return format to be an RDD.

So the RDD:

```
[(4, 'a'), (12, 'e'), (2, 'u'), (49, 'y'), (6, 'p')]
```

filtered for the largest 3 keys should return the RDD:

```
[(6,'p'), (12,'e'), (49,'y')]
```

Doing a `sortByKey()` and then `take(N)` returns the values and doesn't result in an RDD, so that won't work.

I could return all of the keys, sort them, find the Nth largest value, and then filter the RDD for key values greater than that, but that seems very inefficient.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need an RDD returned? Are you taking a very large number which won't fit into single machine memory?  If you're not you could just parallelize the returned collection.

Comment: The example is simplified from my actual use case. The value of my key/value pair is a large vector, and I want a subset of hundreds of tuples from thousands of tuples. Returning hundreds of these vector tuples and then making them into another RDD would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**With `RDD`**

A quick but not particularly efficient solution is to follow `sortByKey` use `zipWithIndex` and `filter`:

```
n = 3
rdd = sc.parallelize([(4, 'a'), (12, 'e'), (2, 'u'), (49, 'y'), (6, 'p')])

rdd.sortByKey().zipWithIndex().filter(lambda xi: xi[1] < n).keys()
```

If n is relatively small compared to RDD size a little bit more efficient approach is to avoid full sort:

```
import heapq

def key(kv):
    return kv[0]

top_per_partition = rdd.mapPartitions(lambda iter: heapq.nlargest(n, iter, key))
top_per_partition.sortByKey().zipWithIndex().filter(lambda xi: xi[1] < n).keys()
```

If keys are much smaller than values and order of final output doesn't matter then `filter` approach can work just fine:

```
keys = rdd.keys()
identity = lambda x: x

offset = (keys
    .mapPartitions(lambda iter: heapq.nlargest(n, iter))
    .sortBy(identity)
    .zipWithIndex()
    .filter(lambda xi: xi[1] < n)
    .keys()
    .max())

rdd.filter(lambda kv: kv[0] <= offset)
```

Also it won't keep exact n values in case of ties.

**With `DataFrames`**

You can just `orderBy` and `limit`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

rdd.toDF().orderBy(col("_1").desc()).limit(n)
```

Comment: I'm new to Spark so forgive my ignorance. I read the documentation for zipWithIndex() and it doesn't sound like the index that it creates will be ordered across all the partitions.

"The ordering is first based on the partition index and then the ordering of items within each partition."

So will it index everything across all partitions with the order from sortByKey, or will it only order within each partition and then add a partition index?

Comment: Just finished verifying this solution. It looks good.
Is there another more efficient method?

Comment: Not really. Based on your comment you can try to sort only keys and then filter as you mentioned in the question. It will limit shuffling but there are some trade-offs involved.

Answer (score 0):

A less effort approach since you only want to convert `take(N)` results to new RDD.

```
sc.parallelize(yourSortedRdd.take(Nth))
```

Comment: This loads your N values on the spark driver before reparallelizing, which can fail if your N is large.