# Take n largest element in a Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Hi I am using Java to write some SparkSql code.Now I have a `DataSet<Foo>` and Foo class implement Comparable ,I want to **take n largest element in the dataset as list like `top()`** in JavaRDD, but I didn't found a similar method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sort` followed by `take`? Have you tried it out already?

Comment: If `s` is the size of your dataset and `n` the number of elements you wish to retrieve, how does `n` compare to `s`? Is `n` << `s`?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292879/return-rdd-of-largest-n-values-from-another-rdd-in-spark) provides a solution for the same problem. If `n` << `s` holds, it is best to avoid sorting.

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez But now I am having a Datafrane, how to take n largest element in the dataframe?

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I edited my question so now my question may seems more clearly